# Is there any time-varying directed graph dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, classification, geometric-deep-learning, graph-theory

I am interested in the node classification task for graph data. So far,I've tried it with the Cora dataset, but it is an undirected graph and has word attributes as features. I want to extend this task to a time-varying directed graph. Does anybody know about this kind of dataset?